# Prepared statement doesn't return any rows from a partitioned Mysql 8.0 table using IN clause

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, database-partitioning

If we have two identical tables, except one uses partitions and the other doesn't, like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    created_at DATE
) ;
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ('2023-02-03'), ('2023-02-25');

CREATE TABLE t2 (
    created_at DATE
) 
PARTITION BY RANGE (DAYOFMONTH(created_at)) (
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (16), 
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES ('2023-02-03'), ('2023-02-25');
```

And if we have a short PHP script which queries these tables, like this:

```php
<?php
include 'db.inc.php';
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

$tables = ['t1', 't2'];

$sql_statements = [
    'SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE created_at IN (?, ?)',
    'SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE (created_at = ? OR created_at = ?)'
];

foreach ($tables as $table) {
    foreach ($sql_statements as $id => $sql) {
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare(str_replace('[TABLE]', $table, $sql));
        $stmt->execute(['2023-02-03', '2023-02-25']);
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        echo 'Table: '.$table.'; Statement: '.$id.'; Num rows: '.$result->num_rows."\n";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

We get the following result:

```
Table: t1; Statement: 0; Num rows: 2
Table: t1; Statement: 1; Num rows: 2

Table: t2; Statement: 0; Num rows: 0
Table: t2; Statement: 1; Num rows: 2
```

The question is:
Why does the first statement using `created_at IN (...)` not work when used on the partitioned table?

I tried to provide a minimal working example. That being said, using only one date in the `IN (...)` clause does indeed work with the partitioned table. But as soon as there is more than one, it stops working.

Things that also work as expected:

- using the MySQL CLI instead of PHP MySQLi
- using MySQLi but without prepared statements, e.g. `$mysqli->query(...)`

Things that also don't work:

- using MySQLi with `$stmt->bind_param('ss', $date1, $date2)` instead

My environment:

- mysql  Ver 8.0.32
- PHP 8.1.15
- Fedora Linux 37

Comment: Great thanks for providing MCVE! I wish there was a huge reward for this. It seems your code [works with 5.7](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/47c304acc0a007a0ff4d339c5f0839a7/php/php81/b8080ed52ff6c85d0d646284ed895fd1/) but indeed fails with 8.0

Comment: Thanks for bringing https://phpize.online/ to my attention, didn't know it existed and will probably use it very often from now on (until I forget about it's existence again). Also didn't know what MCVE means, but I know Google :)

Comment: Minimum, Compact, Verifiable Example, the minimum code needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: This is a weird one. Partitions should be completely transparent to the query, and doubly-so to the API that PHP is using. That this is happening is strange enough, but that it's _not_ happening when the query runs via PDO is even stranger.

Comment: I slept it over and decided to double check the PDO example. Surely enough, when  prepared statements are *really* used, PDO [follows the suit](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql80/47c304acc0a007a0ff4d339c5f0839a7/php/php81/1782d11852816c6d485113b7712c902d/)

Comment: So it seems like a C API/Mysql engine bug. And I have a feeling that someone is already working on the issue, at least to file a bug report for mysql.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, what gives you that feeling? I'd be happy to file a bug report, but you seem so sure that someone is already doing that.

Comment: I searched for a bug about this, but found none. So I reported it using your example case: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=110341 I was able to reproduce it without using PHP.

Comment: Interesting that MySQL 8.0.30 does not have this bug: https://dbfiddle.uk/DPbL7FXf so it must be a bug caused by a recent change.